# Can gemstones, rings and the like be charmed in Baldur's Gate?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I have collected a big pile of gemstones, various rings and amulets hoping I could get them imbued with spells or soemthing. I am already into chapter 5 though and they are clogging up my inventory appear to only have pecuniary value.

Is there any other uses I should consider saving them for, or should I just sell my hoard?

Comment: Once, long ago, when I played baldur's gate, I too hoarded gemstones. I managed to completely fill the main character's inventory with them, and then exported and started anew so I could get more and more gemstones. I never sold them, I just stockpiled them. Because they were shiny.

Comment: Yeah, the must have shiny syndrome I appear to suffer from, only perhaps my case is less debilitating. I never considered exporting to get more :)

Comment: later on you will probably be able to recognize the ones that are valuable and that you can profit from from the ones that just clog your inventory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do anything with gems except sell them, so definitely get your money out of them.  Rings and amulets may be magical, but if they are not (use identify) then they should just be sold.  There is no ability in the game to enchant non-magical rings or amulets.

Comment: Thanks, well time to go to see Feldpost. Pity I could have saved myself some serious inventory juggling there.

Answer (score 0):

Some gems/jewelry are required for quests/encounters, and in BG2 upgrading some items, but in general, they're are just for selling. It is a good idea though to sell them to a merchant you know you can get easy access to just in-case you find a quest that needs one.

Comment: This would be a grat additional answer if it contained a list of uses - Angelskin Ring for someone in Baldurs Gate and quite a few uses in BG2 (including a secret area unlocked with Rogue Stone)